# How to remove the size of an input?

Tags: 8, theming

I create a very simple theme with "stable" parent theme.

So far so good.

The size of input is indicated in HTML, and it bothers me a lot for the layout of my forms.

This is an example.

```
<input (...) value="" size="60" maxlength="128">
```

I have of course looked in the stable theme, but in the template input.html.twig, it is only indicated `<input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}`.

I would like to remove the size indication to fully manage my layout in CSS.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do a form alter and remove the size attribute for different fields.

Comment: I try `$form['input']['#size'] = FALSE;` but does not work...

Comment: You have to explain what "not works" means. Did you target the right form field?

Comment: I want to remove all size elements from all my input elements. So I guess I do not have to point to a particular form field? I added the following code to my mytheme.theme file: `function mytheme_form_alter(&$form) {$form['input']['#size'] = FALSE;}`

Comment: And setting this input `width: 100%;` doesn't work, really?

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old but here a solution

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_form_element().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  // remove size
  unset($variables['element']['#size'], $variables['element']['#attributes']['size'], $variables['attributes']['size']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change or remove size of field by changing `$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['value']['#size']`

For example you can set the size of the title field to `120` using:

```
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#size'] = 120;
```

Use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to print the `$form` to get the exacte location of the `#size`.

**UPDATE**
To remove the size set it to `NULL` try with

```
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#size'] = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks berramou, but I want to delete size elements, not modify them.

Comment: did you try `unset($form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#size'])` ?

Comment: I tried but it does not work (the size always appears)